# Api gateway responsibility: good practices (authorisation, request transformation)

Tags: architecture, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I am considering to use an api gateway on top of my micro-services. But there are some architectural questions for which I don't have clear answers, so I would like to get an opinion from community. Also it would be great if you can share your ideas about good and bad practices. So to make this question-post easy to read I have two main sections "questions" and "details"

## Questions

### Should Api gateway take responsibility of authorisation and request transformation?

The question is mostly, what is gateway: is it just a bridge between api users and micro-services. Or is it moderator of micro-services? Please see section "Gateway implementing strategies" for more information.

### In case of using Amazon API Gateway, is it good practice to make transformation and authorisation of requests with additional layer of lambda functions?

If I will choose to go with Amazon API Gateway, and answer to the previous question will be "Gateway should act as a moderator of micro-services". Than I'll need to handle request/response transformations and authorisation via Amazon lambdas, which will mean that I'll have another layer below the gateway. So the question is: Is it a good practice to have this kind of architecture?

## Details

### Technologies

- Spring Boot 2.0
- JWT
- **Spring cloud gateway** or **Amazon Api Gateway** (depending on the answers)

### Services

We have the following micro-services in our system

#### ServiceA

**Endpoint GET /api/resources/{dataId}/admin-endpoint**

*headers - authorisation : bearer token*

this endpoint is accessible only to users with ADMIN role (In case of request from user without that role 403 http status will be returned with response).

Please note that token must be validated by AuthService before processing the request. And after processing the request (in case of non-error http status) token must be refreshed by AuthService (response must contain refreshed token)

**Endpoint GET /api/resources/{dataId}/user-endpoint**

*headers - authorisation : bearer token*

this endpoint is accessible to users with any role

#### AuthService

**Endpoint POST /api/auth/login**

*headers - authorisation : bearer token*

*body - {"username" : String, "password" : String}*

authenticates user: in case of success signed authorisation token will be returned as header of response (bearer JWT token). In case of authentication failure 401 http status will be returned

**Endpoint POST /api/auth/logout**

*headers - authorisation : bearer token*

invalidates authorisation token (by storing token in appropriate table), so that user cannot have access to the protected api with given token

**Endpoint GET /api/auth/validate**

*headers - authorisation : bearer token*

validates given token (must be called before processing request in ServiceA. See Appendix-A for validation checks

*response body - {"role" : , "username" : String}*

### Gateway implementing strategies

#### Gateway is responsible only for routing

With this strategy ServiceA and AuthService are registered as routes in gateway, no additional request transformation is done before processing the request.

ServiceA talks directly to the AuthServer for authorisation and token validation.

**Pros**

- Gateway logic is very simple
- As gateway there is a big variety of frameworks and tools to choose.

**Cons**

- ServiceA and AuthService are strongly coupled
- If I'll need to add ServiceB, than I'll need to do some kind of double job for establishing communication between ServiceB and ServiceA
- Handling failures in AuthService mostly will be done by ServiceA

#### Gateway is responsible for authorisation and request transformation

With this strategy api-gateway will handle token validation with AuthServer, before passing request to ServiceA. And it will also handle token refreshment when ServiceA will give non-error response

**Pros**

- ServiceA is fully decoupled from AuthService
- Adding another ServiceB will be much easier
- Failures of AuthService will be handled by gateway

**Cons**

- Gateway will have more responsibilities than just being a bridge for micro-services
- Amazon Api Gateway most likely will not be a good choice, as handling authorisation and transformation with Amazon lambda-s can be very painful (maybe I am wrong)

### Appendix-A: JWT token validation checks

- Token has valid bearer prefix: "bearer "
- Token is not expired (token has createdAt attribute, which is used to determine whether token is older than 10 mins)
- User exists: user was not deleted after token creation (token has subject attribute, which keeps unique identifier of the user)
- User password hasn't been changed during token lifetime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should API gateway be responsible for authorisation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700178/should-api-gateway-be-responsible-for-authorisation)

Answer (score 0):

In my microservice experience I've learnt that there should be core micorservices that own only business logic, while application logic should be implemented elsewhere. API gateway, as central service that links the external world with internal micorserivces ecosystem, is a good place where to put most of it....and if you need to change your application logic (eg. you want to enable basic auth for some kind of client on a restriced set of apis) you can always add another API gateway to your architecture

In general, api gateways are not load balancers or routers....are microservices that can do everything. Important is that the architect make them do the right things